# Grails unit test cases are not working after upgrading from 1.3.7 to 2.4.4

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have migrated Grails from 1.3.7 to version 2.4.4. And now when I run unit test cases it fails with below reason. There are 45 plus test cases which fail with below exception:

**Tests in error:**

> testEdit(AddressControllerTest): No signature of method: static entity.Address.get() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]

My class name is AddressController.groovy

```
def edit = {
    def quoteInstance = Quote.get( params.id )

    if(!quoteInstance) {
        flash.message = "Quote not found with id ${params.id}"
        redirect(action:list)
    }
    else {
        return [ quoteInstance : quoteInstance ]
    }
}
```

And this is the before method:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    flash = [ : ]
    AddressController.metaClass.getFlash= { -> flash }

    params = [ : ]
    AddressController.metaClass.getParams = { -> params }

    redirectParams = [ : ]
    AddressController.metaClass.'static'.redirect = { Map args ->
    redirectParams = args }

    renderParams= [ : ]
    AddressController.metaClass.render = { Map args -> renderParams = args }
}
```

And the actual test case is:

```
@Test
public void testEdit(){

    params['id'] = 123 ;

    Quote.metaClass.static.get = { int id ->
        assertEquals params.id, id
        return null
    }

    QuoteController cc = new QuoteController()
    cc.edit()

    assertEquals 'Quote not found with id 123', flash.message
    assertEquals cc.list, redirectParams.action
}
```

I suspect the GUnit jar class might have been change.

Comment: Don't you think you are migrating to wrong version. Directly migrate to grails 3 otherwise be ready to face the hell of Grails.

Comment: Thanks @VinayPrajapati. I am upgrading the java version from 1.7 to 1.8 and unfortunately grails 1.3.4 is not compatible with java 1.8. We have upgrading  the java version to 1.8 and grails to 2.4.4 and now running into lots of issues.

Comment: I meant to upgrade to grails 3.0 and use java-7

Comment: @NishanthPandey "I am upgrading the java version from 1.7 to 1.8" - FYI... Grails 2.5 is the first version for which we really support Java 1.8.